# MyBatis, nested results for collection is empty

Tags: collections, mybatis

I'm following the example in the MyBatis website to create a mapper that has a nested collection, when I do a select operation my object (Provider) is return but the collection inside it (ProviderParameter) is empty, when I go to the database tool and apply the same query I get the expected result (the collection is return too).

Here is my mapper:

```
   <resultMap id="Provider" type="xxx.Provider">
        <result column="idProvider" property="idProvider"/>
        <result column="providerType" property="providerType"/>
        <result column="username" property="username"/>
        <result column="password" property="password"/>
        <result column="licenceInformation" property="licenseInformation"/>
        <collection property="parameters" ofType="xxx.ProviderParameter">
            <result column="idProviderParameter" property="idProviderParameter"/>
            <result column="name" property="name"/>
            <result column="value" property="value"/>
        </collection>
    </resultMap>
```

And the select:

```
<select id="getProviderById" resultType="xxx.Provider">
    select P.idProvider         as idProvider
          ,P.providerType       as providerType
          ,P.username           as username
          ,P.password           as password
          ,P.licenceInformation as licenceInformation
          ,PP.idProviderParameter as idProviderParameter
          ,PP.name              as name
          ,PP.value             as value
     from [dbo].[msg_Provider] AS P 
     left outer join [dbo].[msg_ProviderParameter] AS PP on P.idProvider = PP.idProvider     
     where P.idProvider = #{idProvider}
</select>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was that in the select I put resultType instead of resultMap,

So the select should be like:

```
    <select id="getProviderById" resultMap="Provider">
    select P.idProvider         as idProvider
          ,P.providerType       as providerType
          ,P.username           as username
          ,P.password           as password
          ,P.licenceInformation as licenceInformation
          ,PP.idProviderParameter as idProviderParameter
          ,PP.name              as name
          ,PP.value             as value
     from [dbo].[msg_Provider] AS P 
     left outer join [dbo].[msg_ProviderParameter] AS PP on P.idProvider = PP.idProvider     
     where P.idProvider = #{idProvider}
</select>
```